# Prove that an hyperboloid contains two lines

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

Given the hyperboloid $x^2+y^2-z^2=1$ and the point $p=(1,0,0)$, I want to prove that there are two lines passing through the point $p$ and they are fully contained into the hyperboloid.

Exercise from my Differential Calculus subject, so we need to prove it using derivatives and gradients.

Comment: What have you tried? Are there any intuitive facts about gradients and the defintion of lines in $3$D space you can use?

Comment: @NinadMunshi Any concept about gradients and lines can be used. I calculated the tangent plane on the point $p$, but it doesn't give me any helpful information.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure about that, after all tangent planes are just a span of lines. If you have two lines immersed in the hyperboloid, and they intersect at $p$, what do you think their relationship is with the tangent plane?

Comment: in other words, find the intersection of the tangent plane with the surfac

Comment: They must be contained into the tangent plane, right? Because if they weren't, they would intersect the plain in $p$ and then go outside the hyperboloid.

Comment: yes. Again, you say you found the tangent plane. What is the tangent plane, and what is its intersection with the hyperboloid? These should be expressed as statements using the variables $x,y,z$

Comment: This all sounds overcomplicated. By inspection the lines $(1,-t,t)$ and $(1,t,t)$ meet the criteria.